# How to share R package locally without using Github/miniCRAN/other internet sites

Tags: r, package, r-package

I created a local R-package (gmad) on one computer. I want to copy this package to a server and continue developing it.

I have the "project folder" in my current working directory where I wrote the R code etc. (includes the R functions explicitly saved in separate files). [image: contents of "R" in the project folder]

There is also a folder with the same name in the directory containing all the installed packages - which has a sub-dolder named "R" but unlike the previous folder, it does not contain separate files for different functions. I'm guessing this is the "installed" version of the package and that I won't be able to modify the R code in it.

[image: contents of "R" in the installed folder - <code>.libPaths()</code>]

What is the best way to copy this to the new computer. On the original computer, `.libPaths()` shows two locations for installed packages. I don't really care about these on this machine however I want to follow the correct procedure for the server. What is the best practice - should there be only one location and if so, what should it be?

Comment: The server has restrictions on connecting to the internet. So Github isn't an option at the moment. I can physcially copy files though.